# MSBuild Wildcard Negative Lookbehind

Tags: msbuild

I have a directory that contains:

```
foo.css
foo.min.css
bar.css
bar.min.css
```

It also contains a bunch of other random files like images.

I want to write a selector that can use wildcards to select ALL the files in the directory EXCEPT the non-minified .css files.

This works:

```
<MyFiles Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)**\*.*"
         Exclude="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)foo.css;$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)bar.css" />
```

But I have to explicitly list the files to exclude. Not sure how to create a negative lookbehind where if the file ends with .css and is not preceded by .min then exclude it.

Comment: if you only have minified and non-minified files in your folder (as in your example) - just include only minified ones, however, this won't work if you have other extensions and want them to be included

Comment: Exactly. That's my point. I do have other extensions that I want included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <MyStyles Include="**\*.css" Exclude="**\*.min.css" />
    <MyFiles Include="**\*" Exclude="@(MyStyles)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="MyCompiles">
    <Message Text="%(MyFiles.Identity)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```